# how to implement Smart Face Pdf Viewer Using WebLink?

Tags: smartface.io

I want to a Open my PDF from a web link on web browser,
i tried taking webview in my page and it was working with web link,but am not able to display a PDF Web Link,
Please answer my question if any one knows,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

With the new release of Smartface (4.5.0), you will be able to reach your local files.

For now, you can show files that exists in internet, I mean you can use url's to show these kind of files on WebView object.

Comment: Hi , i have tried to show in web view object but it was not working,please tell how to display pdf urls on web view
Thanks

Comment: Hi Suresh, can you give an example pdf url?

Comment: Hi Merve....here is my url....
http://10.0.0.190:8181/BookingDocuments?type=printed&id=1sx5lz4-qq6pmo235k23ni59lmlzwktycpa1sbg